# How do I get signatures for bazel targets and add them to dependency graph?

Tags: bazel

I've been using the bazel build system and was interested in doing a few things but cannot find references if they are possible / how.

In particular, I wanted to

1. See if a particular target requires a rebuild (I.e. no cache hits) without rebuilding it. Is there a bazel query command/flags to do this say?
2. Getting a signature of a target so I can see if a target may have changed compared to say a different git commit
3. Generating a dependency graph with signatures (as in similar to doing --output=graph for bazel query but ofcourse not using query as that doesnt build the targets). Then I can compare two graphs seeing what targets have been affected and also any new/removed edges/nodes (the second part --output=graph does already).

There is probably a very manual way of doing some of these by sha-ing files and associating them to the output from bazel query 'deps()'. It seems like a task I should be able to use bazel tools to do directly.

I've checked bazel references/guides but couldnt find anything to do the above.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have run across [Tinder/bazel-diff](https://github.com/Tinder/bazel-diff) which sounds like it does some similar operations. If you dig around there, you might find APIs you're looking for.